Retopology always turns transparent?
I just upgraded to the latest version of blender and I've been doing some retopology on some of my old projects. However, every time I try, the retopology output version becomes translucent, texture vanishes, and it becomes a slightly blue tinted gray. I've never had this happen before in older versions of blender so I'm assuming it's something new? It has the material and texture on it, still all the same material settings, but it doesn't appear on the object anymore in viewpoint. The object is translucent as if it's at 30% opacity.
This happens both when I use blender's built in modifier "remesh" as well as the blender addon "quadremesher"
How do I make it fully opaque in viewport and with its texture back on again? It's very perplexing. Google and YouTube tutorials have been totally unhelpful as all I get are tutorials on how to make things like windows look transparent after render. I'm trying to get things to stop being transparent before render.

Instead of opening the old versions of your files in Blender 4.x, try importing or appending the relevant contents into a native Blender 4.x file, then rewiring the various interconnections (such as the assigning of materials). See if the problem persists.

I'm still not sure why it does that, but I did try exporting the object files after they're remeshed then importing them back into blender, which results in them no longer being transparent. Still an odd situation. Thanks for your help!
